# PyFlink - JSON file sink?

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

Is it possible to use a JSON file sink in the Table API and/or DataStream API the same way as for CSV ?

Thanks !

**Code**

```
my_sink_ddl = f"""
    create table mySink (
        id STRING,
        dummy_item STRING
    ) with (
        'connector.type' = 'filesystem',
        'format.type' = 'json',
        'connector.path' = 'output.json'
    )
"""
```

**Error**

```
TableException: findAndCreateTableSink failed.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, according to the Jira [FLINK-17286 Integrate json to file system connector](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-17286) and the corresponding pull request [[FLINK-17286][connectors / filesystem]Integrate json to file system connector #12010](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/12010), it is possible starting from Flink `1.11`. Prior to Flink `1.11` I believe it was not supported.

You need to use following config:

```
... with (
        'connector' = 'filesystem',
        'format' = 'json',
        'path' = 'output_json' -- This must be a directory
    )
```

Plus following environment definition:

```
t_env = BatchTableEnvironment.create(   environment_settings=EnvironmentSettings.new_instance().in_batch_mode().use_blink_planner().build())
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mikalai. Any idea how to correctly specify the sink then ?

Comment: Please, have a look on this doc for 1.11 flink, it might help: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/connectors/filesystem.html

From what I now - it should be 
with (
        'connector' = 'filesystem',
        'format' = 'json',
        'path' = 'output.json'
    )

Comment: Using those attribute names leads now to another error: TableException: BatchTableSink or OutputFormatTableSink required to emit batch Table.

Comment: Could you please confirm you are using flink 1.11 ?

Comment: Also, according to the documentation, the path parameter is specified for a directory not for a file and you can’t get a human-readable file in the path that you declare. So, `path` should be a directory.

Comment: Version is 1.11.2. I just changed `path` to empty directory using `file:///path/to/whatever` syntax. Same error.

Comment: What environment do you use, `BatchTableEnvironment` ? Could you please provide the environment configuration peace of code ?

Comment: `env = ExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()`
`t_config = TableConfig()`
`t_env = BatchTableEnvironment.create(env, t_config)`

Comment: COuld you please try this one instead ? `t_env = BatchTableEnvironment.create(
  environment_settings=EnvironmentSettings.new_instance().in_batch_mode().use_blink_planner().build())`

Comment: If you have more info, feel free to share. Thanks again Mikalai !

Comment: I think the key point is the table planner selected - blink vs flink. My understanding is that the old planner (flink) does not support new converters and new syntax and this causes the error.

Comment: Also, the default execution mode is streaming, so you need to explicitly set it to batch. I'd expect that the default planner is Blink, though, since it is the default in the Table API from Flink 1.10. Like Mikalai said, most new features are not backported to the old planner, but built on the "new" Blink planner instead. Thanks for working through the hiccups! I'll patch up the PyFlink documentation as it's really not clear for batch jobs.